# .NET C# - Could not load file or assembly [...] or one of it's dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified

Tags: c#, .net, dependencies, runtime-error

I am trying to use MathNet.Filtering (https://github.com/mathnet/mathnet-filtering) and I receive during runtime the error `Could not load the file or assembly 'MathNet.Filtering, Version=0.7.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null or one of its dependencies . The system cannot find the file specified`. This happens when trying to use any part of the MathNet.Filtering class.

Such as
`MathNet.Fitering.OnlineFilter myFilt = MathNet.Filtering.OnlineFilter.CreateBandpass(MathNet.Filtering.ImpulseResponse.Finite, 8000,100,15000,50);`

I am already referencing MathNet.Numerics as it is a dependency to MathNet.Filtering.
I am compiling and running with .NET 4.6.1 and the dll for MathNet is built to target .NET 4.6.1.

Using dotPeek I can see there are other dependencies:

- MathNet.Numerics (already referenced version 4.9.1.0)
- mscorlib
- System
- System.Core
- System.Numerics
- System.ValueTuple

[[image]]

I am struggling to see why I am getting `Could not load the file or assembly` . There are no external references missing.

Is the problem related to **System.ValueTuple?**

I can use the MathNet.Numerics classes without any issue, this has all the same dependencies *except System.ValueTuple*

[image]

But when I try and explicitly reference System.ValueTuple's DLL I receive

`System.ValueTuple exists in both [path to reference] and C:\Windows\[...]\mscorlib.dll`

Any ideas what is going on here? Stuck at this for hours

Thanks

Comment: You might get some more information about the error using [fuslogvw](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/tools/fuslogvw-exe-assembly-binding-log-viewer)